# why does this ajax error happen when I post html with stringify

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, vb.net

Why does this ajax error happen when I try post html in the string with stringify.

It looks like the stringify escapes the charactors automatically.

do I have to escape?  thanks

```
var s;

//s = "my test test"; //if I post this it works

s = "my test test<br />"; //if I post this it break when I add the html

        var a = { "myText": JSON.stringify(s) };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.aspx",
            data: a,
            success: function (data) {

                  //pass

            },
            error: function () {
            alert("error");

            }
        });
```

then on the page load I'm trying to read the posted data with

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Form("myText")
```

Comment: can you confirm if you can reach your url: test.aspx

Comment: if there is no html then it will read the url: test.aspx. but the moment I add the html, it  goes to the error in the ajax. thanks

Comment: I think the error is because the Request Validation in ASP.net. It prevents HTML to be uploaded. Try disabling it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var s = "my test test<br />",
a = { "myText": s };
a = JSON.stringify(a)
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.aspx",
    data: a,
    success: function (data) {
          //pass
    },
    error: function () {
    alert("error");

    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but if I do it like this then my code behind wont read the variable "myText"    what I m posting is this. { "myText": JSON.stringify(tableOBJ) };  table OBJ is a whole bunch of table row objects

Comment: if i do this then why wont HttpContext.Current.Request.Form("myText") show the passing data? thanks

Comment: Well, not exactly sure about it, as I don't have almost any knowledge in server-side programming, but I'm guessing that it's because you are posting a string to the server and expecting to receive an object. To read the data this way, I think you should first do some json decode. But anyway, as you just need to post a whole bunch of html as a single string, you just have to post it, without JSON.stringify it: 
    var s = "my test test<br />",
    a = { "myText": s };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.aspx",
        data: a,
        success: function (data) {
        }
});

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call JSON.stringify().

JSON.stringify is intended to serialize the object to JSON string, but you're passing a string to it and it's wrong.

Just pass the object with $.ajax() call:

```
var s = "my test test<br />";
.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.aspx",
    data: {
        myText: s
    },
    success: function (data) {
          //pass
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Also [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#sending-data-to-server):

> The data option can contain either a query string of the form
>   key1=value1&key2=value2, or a map of the form {key1: 'value1', key2:
>   'value2'}.

So in our particular example we used a "map" of the form, namely JavaScript object.